# Why is VC++ Resource Editor not putting auto-generated code in the right place?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

In MyControl.h I have:

```
class CMyControl: public CRichEditCtrl
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC( CMyControl)
public:
    CMyControl();
    virtual ~CMyControl();
public:

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CMyControl)
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

    // Generated message map functions
protected:
    //{{AFX_MSG(CMyControl)
    //}}AFX_MSG

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnEnKillfocus();
    afx_msg void OnEnChange();
    afx_msg void OnEnMsgfilter(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
};

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.
```

Whenever I use the resource editor to add a message handler or event override method or a dialog control member variable, they always get added at the end of the class. Isn't the whole point of the {{AFX...}} blocks to keep this organised?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578293/are-things-like-afx-msg-decorators-still-used-by-vs-mfc